# negative value for "mean_squared_error"

Tags: regression, scikit-learn, linear-regression, lasso-regression

I am using scikit and using `mean_squared_error` as a scoring function for model evaluation in cross_val_score.

```
rms_score = cross_validation.cross_val_score(model, X, y, cv=20, scoring='mean_squared_error')
```

I am using `mean_squared_error` as it is a regression problem and the estimators (model) used are `lasso`, `ridge` and `elasticNet`.

For all these estimators, I am getting `rms_score` as negative values. How is it possible, given the fact that the differences in y values are squared.

[image]

Comment: It would be helful, if you provide a minimial example, which reproduces that behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You get the mean_squared_error with sign flipped returned by cross_validation.cross_val_score. There is an issued opened for that (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2439), it's controversial if that is an API- or documentation bug.