# Getting a negative score on using LassoCV.score() in scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have tested 2 models using LassoCV, one without any explicit alphas list, and the other with alphas list-

```
Model1 = LassoCV(alphas=None, copy_X=True, cv=None, eps=0.001, fit_intercept=True,
max_iter=1000, n_alphas=100, normalize=True, precompute='auto',
tol=0.0001, verbose=False)

Model2 = LassoCV(alphas=[0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 1.0, 10.0], copy_X=True, cv=None, eps=0.001,
fit_intercept=True, max_iter=1000, n_alphas=100, normalize=True,
precompute='auto', tol=0.0001, verbose=False)
```

I am using the **diabetes dataset** from **sklearn.datasets** and the data partition scheme from this example-
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html#example-linear-model-plot-ols-py

Using modelX.score for both of them the respective errors are-

Model1 : **0.47235439555084802**

Model2 : **-0.15271790306245214**

On checking the alpha values, I see that for Model1 it is **0.0021734898275546505** whereas for Model2 it is **10.0**.

Why does it get a negative RMS value?

This doesn't help m at all-
[negative value for "mean_squared_error"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19993711/negative-value-for-mean-squared-error)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `score` method of a `LassoCV` instance returns the R-Squared score, which can be negative. See the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html):

> Best possible score is 1.0, lower values are worse... Unlike most
>   other scores, R^2 score may be negative (it need not actually be the
>   square of a quantity R).

So a negative score just means that the particular model is performing quite poorly.

Comment: Yes, I see it here- 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.html#sklearn.linear_model.LassoCV.score

The R2 score = 1 - (u/v) where u/v can be greater than one.

You might want to correct the link to your answer. I wasn't using the scikit.metric.r2_score function.

Comment: @goelakash You weren't using it directly, but `LassoCV` calls `scikit.metric.r2_score` when computing the score.